# split method in python

Tags: python, split

Does someone know what `[44:]` is doing in statement `huck_finn_text.split('CHAPTER ')[44: ]` and why 44?

```py
    huck_finn_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/bakuzen/bsu-fds/raw/master/lec/huck_finn.txt'
    huck_finn_text = read_url(huck_finn_url)
    huck_finn_chapters = huck_finn_text.split('CHAPTER ')[44:]

    # Display the chapters of Huckleberry Finn in a table.
    Table().with_column('Chapters', huck_finn_chapters)
```

Output is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oFtU.jpg)

Comment: That is splitting the text at each occurrence of the word 'CHAPTER ', and saving the 44th to the last occurrence in the huck_finn_chapters variable.

Comment: Apparently, there are 44 instances of `CHAPTER ` in the document prior to the instance that actually indicates the first chapter.  Perhaps the document contains its own table of contents, and this is skipping over it?  I can't tell without looking at the actual document, but the URL in your code isn't working.

Comment: URL is updated now @jasonharper

Comment: Thank you @marcdtheking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called `slicing`.

In this example you're slicing a list:

```
huck_finn_chapters = huck_finn_text.split('CHAPTER ')[44:]
```

And you are slicing the list from `44` index to the end.

Look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/11101156

Answer (score 0):

`split` method separate texts in the url with a character or a word that here is 'Chapter '.

You can read about it here:
**https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp**

Answer (score 0):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits a string, so it finds all occurrences of `'CHAPTER '` (that is the letters "CHAPTER" followed by a space), and returns a list of all the text between them.

`something[a:b]` is the [slice operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), it means to take all the items from number `a` to number `b`. For example, if `a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` then `a[2:4] == [5, 6]`. You can omit the first number to take everything from the start, or omit the second number to take everything until the end. In this case, `some_list[44:]` means to skip the first 44 items, and return the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The split method will return a list, and the [44:] means return every item in the list after the 44th. For example:

```
myList = ["hello","hi","yo","whatsup"]
print(myList[2:])
#will return ['yo', 'whatsup']
```